# Put in variables from JSON Object

Tags: java, android, json, loopj

Hi I'm linking a test android app to a MySQL database from an echo of JSON from a .php file.

I was able to populate an ArrayList with the whole data, but now i'd like to separate the data into variables and i can't really find out the way.

I'm using loopJ library to make the JSON communication

My MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    ListView list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvLista);

        getData();
    }

    public void getData()
    {
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        String url = "http://www.kukitosoft.com/android/api.php";

       // RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
       // params.put("campo", "valor a fitrar");
        //Esto iria en el null del client.post

        client.post(url, null, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                if (statusCode == 200)
                {
                    loadList(getDataJSON(new String(responseBody)));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }
        });
    }


    public void loadList(ArrayList<String> data)
    {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getDataJSON(String response)
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try
        {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
            String texto;

            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
            {
                texto = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id") + " " +
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre") + " " +
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("descripcion") + " " +
                        jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("calificacion") + " ";
                list.add(texto);
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to separate all values by tags (e.g. "id", "nombre") in an individual list?

Comment: Yes, it's what i want

Comment: You will have to Parse it and save it in a model object. create a model class with id, nombre etc as parameters. Then create a class object and assign each parameter its value using jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id") and then add that object to arraylist to have a list of objects having individual values.
While populating you can use the same list to show on UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a pojo class with different getter/setter for your required fields.

```
  public class MyResponse(){

    private List<String> idList;
    private List<String> nombreList;
    private List<String> descList;
    private List<String> califList;

    public void setIdList(List<String> list){
    this.idList = list;
    }

    public void getIdList(){
    return idList;
    }

    public void setNombreList(List<String> list){
    this.nombreList = list;
    }

    public void getNombreList(){
    return nombreList;
    }

    public void setDescList(List<String> list){
    this.descList = list;
    }

    public void getDescList(){
    return descList;
    }

    public void setCalifList(List<String> list){
    this.califList = list;
    }

    public void getCalifList(){
    return califList;
    }

}
```

Now parse each response and add in the list of **MyResponse** type

```
         public MyResponse getDataJSON(String response)
                    {
                        MyResponse myResponse = new MyResponse();
                        ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        ArrayList<String> nombreList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        ArrayList<String> descList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        ArrayList<String> califList = new ArrayList<String>();

                        try
                        {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                            {
                              idList.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id"));

   nombreList.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("nombre"));
                              descList.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("descripcion"));
                              califList.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("calificacion"));
                            }

                            myResponse.setIdList(idList);
                            myResponse.setNombreList(nombreList);
                            myResponse.setDescList(descList);
                            myResponse.setCalifList(califList);

                            return myResponse;
                        }

                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return list;
                    }
```

To retrieve back the data from **getDataJSON**()

```
     MyResponse myResponse = getDataJSON(new String(responseBody)));
     ArrayList<String> idList = myResponse.getIdList();
     ArrayList<String> nombreList = myResponse.getNombreList();
     ArrayList<String> descList = myResponse.getDescList();
     ArrayList<String> califList = myResponse.getCalifList();
```

Comment: Where do you give values to 'idList','nombreList', etc. after the 'for'?

Comment: Oh thank you so much! now i understand the way to do it, thank you again!

Comment: could you tell me how to access for example to the element 1 when  use MyResponse.GetidList?

Comment: Answer updated! Also check the getDataJSON() method.